# How do I switch product pages using Ajax?

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, knockoutjs, product-page

I need to implement a **button** on the **product page** to switch products **(NEXT and PREV)** without reloading the page **(AJAX or KnockoutJS)**.

Now I have **ID NEXT and PREV product**. Please tell me how it can be implemented?

[image]

Comment: Try this module https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-product-previous-next

Comment: Ansar, how make it via ajax? Your module doesn't have ajax implementation